# Unbinding input type file button with jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input type file element:

```
<input type="file" name="val1" />
```

And jquery:

```
$("input[name='val1']").off("click");
```

But the above JS script (already included in `$(function() { });` block) doesn't work, means I can click on `Browse...` button. I want to disable it or disable click event on this input element.

What's the mistake with my jquery code ? Or it is not possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to disable the element.

```
$("input[name='val1']").prop("disabled", true);​
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/A7ak9/)**

Answer (score 4):

[`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) removes an event handler. What you're talking about doing is preventing the default action of a click on the file input, which is a different thing.

Either disable the input or, if you want it enabled but non-responsive for some reason, you can prevent the default action of the click using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and `false`:

```
$("input[name='val1']").on("click", false);
```

[Gratuitous example](http://jsbin.com/utogur) | [source](http://jsbin.com/utogur/edit)

From the `on` docs:

> `handler(EventObject)`: The value `false` is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does `return false`.

...and of course `return false` from a handler prevents the default and stops propagation.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the input.

```
$("input[name='val1']").prop("disabled", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/DwBTD/